# Переход на страницу

Tags: flash, actionscript

Есть анимированное меню во флеше, внедряется в сайт  и все работает, но при нажатии на карандаш (он же и кнопка) происходит переход на страницу, но в другой вкладке. Как сделать чтоб переход осуществлялся в той же вкладке?

Вот код перехода одной из кнопок, он работает, но может с ним что-то не то:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("content.php/?act=kontakti"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("content.php/?act=kontakti"), "_self");
```

> `"_self" указывает текущий фрейм в текущем окне.`
> `"_blank" определяет новое окно.`
> `"_parent" указывает родительский объект текущего фрейма.`
> `"_top" указывает фрейм самого верхнего уровня в текущем окне.`

[navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#navigateToURL()).